# How to use Popen instead of check_call?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

I am running Debian 6 squeeze with python version 2.6. I have two subprocess codes like this:

```
rsync_out = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source], 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
command = subprocess.check_call(('grep', '\.'), stdin=rsync_out.stdout)
```

It is working exactly the way I wanted but there's no check_call available for python 2.6. How can call the second command with `subprocess.Popen`?

Tried like this but didn't work:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '\.'], stdin=rsync_out.stdout).communicate()[0]
```

I get this error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to get the return code of the second command? Try this:

```
rsync_out = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
command = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '\.'], stdin=rsync_out.stdout)
command.communicate()
returnCode = command.returncode
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'stdout'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'returncode'

Comment: It's working fine now. But the problem is where are the values stored. I can't get any value on returnCode.